# Prawn the horizontal line from the left border/edge in PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I use gem prawn to generate pdf file. I want to have horizontal line `105 mm from top, 1pt line, #000`. I've set left margin and top margin (I need it in the rest of the pdf) as follow:

```
LEFT_MARGIN = 25.mm
TOP_MARGIN = 44.mm

  def folding_marks
    stroke_color '#000'
    stroke_horizontal_line(0, 100, at: TOP_MARGIN + 61.mm)
  end
```

How to skip the left margin to have the line start right on the left edge?

If I just simply remove the `LEFT_MARGIN` I'll have a horizontal line not from the left edge but still with some kind of margin.
[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `#canvas` method to temporarily reset the bounding box to the full page:

```rb
canvas do
  folding_marks
end
```